# Persist object with two foreign identities in doctrine

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have created an entity using the yml-syntax in my symfony bundle, in the Resources/config/doctrine folder:

```
Sulu\Bundle\TranslateBundle\Entity\Translation:
type: entity
table: tr_translations
id:
    code:
        type: string
        column: idCodes
        associationKey: id
    catalogue:
        type: string
        column: idCatalogues
        associationKey: id
fields:
    value:
        type: text
manyToOne:
    code:
        targetEntity: Code
        inversedBy: tr_codes
        joinColumn:
            name: idCodes
            referencedColumnName: id
    catalogue:
        targetEntity: Catalogue
        inversedBy: tr_catalogues
        joinColumn:
            name: idCatalogues
            referencedColumnName: id
```

This part is working correctly. But when I create some objects like in the following code, I get an error message that I have to use the flush method, in order to get IDs for the foreign keys.

This is the code snippet I am currently using:

```
    // create a new package and catalogue for the import
    $package = new Package();
    $package->setName($this->getName());
    $catalogue = new Catalogue();
    $catalogue->setLocale($this->getLocale());
    $catalogue->setPackage($package);

    $this->em->persist($package);
    $this->em->persist($catalogue);

    // load the file, and create a new code/translation combination for every message
    $fileCatalogue = $loader->load($this->getFile(), $this->getLocale());
    foreach ($fileCatalogue->all()['messages'] as $key => $message) {
        $code = new Code();
        $code->setPackage($package);
        $code->setCode($key);
        $code->setBackend(true);
        $code->setFrontend(true);

        $translate = new Translation();
        $translate->setCode($code);
        $translate->setValue($message);
        $translate->setCatalogue($catalogue);

        $this->em->persist($code);
        $this->em->flush(); //FIXME no flush in between, if possible
        $this->em->persist($translate);
    }

    // save all the changes to the database
    $this->em->flush();
```

If I don't call the flush in the foreach loop I get the following error, which I totally understand, but isn't there a more elegant solution for this problem?

> Doctrine\ORM\ORMException : Entity of type
>   Sulu\Bundle\TranslateBundle\Entity\Translation has identity through a
>   foreign entity Sulu\Bundle\TranslateBundle\Entity\Code, however this
>   entity has no identity itself. You have to call
>   EntityManager#persist() on the related entity and make sure that an
>   identifier was generated before trying to persist
>   'Sulu\Bundle\TranslateBundle\Entity\Translation'. In case of Post
>   Insert ID Generation (such as MySQL Auto-Increment or PostgreSQL
>   SERIAL) this means you have to call EntityManager#flush() between both
>   persist operations.

Comment: Me too same problem. Can't find any better solution than flush more than 1 time. Hope someone know the soution

Comment: If you persist all the Code entities (but not the Translation entities) inside the loop and have a $pairs[] = array($code, $translate); You can wait to flush until after the loop finishes, then iterate through the pairs in a second loop, assign the correct code to each translation and persist each translation. Then outside the loop you can run a second flush operation. You'll have to loop through the data twice, but this can reduce hundreds of flushes down to two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, as per [Doctrine Docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#persisting-entities) you have to call flush to get IDs for your foreign keys:

> Generated entity identifiers / primary keys are guaranteed to be
>   available after the next successful flush operation that involves the
>   entity in question. You can not rely on a generated identifier to be
>   available directly after invoking persist. The inverse is also true.
>   You can not rely on a generated identifier being not available after a
>   failed flush operation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like the following?

YAML:

```
Sulu\Bundle\TranslateBundle\Entity\Translation:
type: entity
table: tr_translations
id:
    code:
        type: string
        column: idCodes
        associationKey: id
    catalogue:
        type: string
        column: idCatalogues
        associationKey: id
fields:
    value:
        type: text
manyToOne:
    code:
        targetEntity: Code
        cascade: ["persist"]
        inversedBy: tr_codes
        joinColumn:
            name: idCodes
            referencedColumnName: id
    catalogue:
        targetEntity: Catalogue
        cascade: ["persist"]
        inversedBy: tr_catalogues
        joinColumn:
            name: idCatalogues
            referencedColumnName: id
```

In your class Translation

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->code = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->catalogue = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function addCatalogue($catalogue)
{
    $this->catalogue[] = $catalogue;

    return $this;
}

public function addCode($code)
{
    $this->code[] = $code;

    return $this;
}
```

Then your code can be something like this:

```
$package = new Package();
$package->setName($this->getName());
$catalogue = new Catalogue();
$catalogue->setLocale($this->getLocale())->setPackage($package);

$fileCatalogue = $loader->load($this->getFile(), $this->getLocale());
foreach ($fileCatalogue->all()['messages'] as $key => $message) {
    $code = new Code();
    $code->setPackage($package)
         ->setCode($key)
         ->setBackend(true)
         ->setFrontend(true);
    $translate = new Translation();
    $translate->addCode($code)
              ->setValue($message)
              ->addCatalogue($catalogue);
    $this->em->persist($translate);
}

$this->em->flush();
```

Note:
cascade: ["persist"] - Cascades persist operations to the associated entities. [Link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)

Comment: I have played around with this cascade property, but I handled it a little bit different... Will try it again later today, thank you so far!

Comment: Could test it earlier than anticipated, but unfortunately it didn't work. I added the cascade persist part and only persisted the translate. It still doesn't work, I am getting the same error message. I also tried to add the catalogue and code to collections as you did, which didn't work as well (and btw also don't match my specification, one translation should only have one code and one catalogue). Thank you anyway!